# Problem with alignment of coefficients

Tags: tables, margins, alignment, textwidth

I have a problem with the alignment of coefficients in this table. I tried modifying the margins with the geometry pack, without success. I don't really know what to do! I modified this table from an orginal version that I saved in .tex using the command esttab in Stata. I just want every number aligned.

For readibility, I also provide it on pastebin.
https://pastebin.com/chH9uvGD

```
\documentclass[12,legalpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\raggedleft{\caption{Explaining imperfect representation through costs and benefits}}
{
    \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
        \begin{tabular}{l*{2}{cc}}
        \hline\hline
        \\
                                 &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{Dep. variable: Quality of representation}             \\
                                 &                                                             \\
                                 & Misrepresented    &          &      Indifferent  &          \\
                                 &  \cline{1-4}      &          &                   &          \\
                                 &   Odds Ratio      &     SE   &      Odds Ratio   &   SE     \\
\hline
\\
\textit{Benefits}                                                                              \\
\\
Positive evaluation                &     1.245\sym{***}&  (0.0750)&     1.156\sym{***}&  (0.0459)\\
EU economic policy influence       &     1.015         &  (0.0302)&     1.001         &  (0.0205)\\
\\
\textit{Costs}                                                                              \\
\\
Immigration should decrease        &     0.830\sym{***}&  (0.0364)&     1.007         &  (0.0307)\\
EP doesn't consider citiz. concerns&     0.874\sym{**} &  (0.0451)&     1.022         &  (0.0357)\\
\\
\textit{Context}                                                                              \\
\\
New EU12                           &     0.937         &  (0.0947)&     1.715\sym{***}&   (0.116)\\
EU spending(log)                   &     0.993         &  (0.0510)&     0.953         &  (0.0342)\\
N dimensions party competition     &     0.874\sym{*}  &  (0.0514)&     1.031         &  (0.0401)\\
\\
\textit{Salience}                                                                              \\
\\
My voice counts                    &     0.541\sym{***}&  (0.0675)&     0.967         &  (0.0677)\\
EU deals with imp issues           &     1.003         &  (0.0684)&     0.921         &  (0.0435)\\
Cares which party wins EP elections&     1.104\sym{*}  &  (0.0433)&     1.023         &  (0.0268)\\
Feels European                     &     1.284\sym{**} &  (0.118) &     1.221\sym{***}&  (0.0734)\\
\\
\textit{Controls}                                                                              \\
\\
Education                          &     1.064         &  (0.0491)&     0.945         &  (0.0299)\\
Standard of living                 &     0.919         &  (0.0763)&     0.884\sym{*}  &  (0.0492)\\
Neither left nor right             &     1.127         &  (0.0784)&     1.018         &  (0.0493)\\
Evaluation of govt econ performance&     0.934         &  (0.0349)&     1.037         &  (0.0268)\\
Watch election news on TV          &     0.921         &  (0.0469)&     0.946         &  (0.0332)\\
How many days follows news         &     1.095         &  (0.0713)&     1.221\sym{***}&  (0.0528)\\
\hline
Pseudo R-Square                  &    0.0227         &          &                   &          \\
$\chi^2 $                            &     395.3         &          &                   &          \\
P                                &  0.000000         &          &                   &          \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize Exponentiated coefficients; Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
        \end{tabular}
}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `12` is not a recognized document class option and is thus ignored. Did you mean to write `12pt`? A separate issue: How wide is the textblock; alternatively, how wide are the left-hand and right-hand margins?

Comment: A general comment about the design of your table: Usually, one puts the standard errors in parentheses if they are shown in the same column as the associated coefficients. That's not the case here. Do consider dropping all parentheses around the standard errors. Doing so would greatly de-clutter the table's appearance.

Answer (score 3):

To align the numbers in the data columns on their respective decimal markers, I suggest you load the `dcolumn` package and its `D` column type. Alternatively, load the `siunitx` package and employ its `S` column type; see [@leandriis' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/494798/5001) for an implementation.

I would also like to suggest that you use the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package instead of the basic `\hline` and `\cline` directives. And, to align the start of the caption with the left-hand edge of the `tabular` environment, I suggest you employ the `threeparttable` package and its eponymous environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,legalpaper]{article} % not "12", but "12pt"
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % choose suitable page parameters
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}

\usepackage{dcolumn,booktabs,caption,threeparttable}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false,
              justification=raggedright,
              skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Explaining imperfect representation through costs and benefits}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l*{4}{d{2.5}}@{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Dep. variable: Quality of representation} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Misrepresented} 
  & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Indifferent}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
  & \mc{Odds Ratio} & \mc{SE} 
  & \mc{Odds Ratio} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{SE} \\
\midrule
\textit{Benefits} \\ \addlinespace
Positive evaluation                &     1.245\sym{***}&  (0.0750)&     1.156\sym{***}&  (0.0459)\\
EU economic policy influence       &     1.015         &  (0.0302)&     1.001         &  (0.0205)\\
\\
\textit{Costs} \\ \addlinespace
Immigration should decrease        &     0.830\sym{***}&  (0.0364)&     1.007         &  (0.0307)\\
EP doesn't consider citiz.\ concerns&    0.874\sym{**} &  (0.0451)&     1.022         &  (0.0357)\\
\\
\textit{Context}  \\ \addlinespace
New EU12                           &     0.937         &  (0.0947)&     1.715\sym{***}&   (0.116)\\
EU spending(log)                   &     0.993         &  (0.0510)&     0.953         &  (0.0342)\\
N dimensions party competition     &     0.874\sym{*}  &  (0.0514)&     1.031         &  (0.0401)\\
\\
\textit{Salience} \\ \addlinespace
My voice counts                    &     0.541\sym{***}&  (0.0675)&     0.967         &  (0.0677)\\
EU deals with imp issues           &     1.003         &  (0.0684)&     0.921         &  (0.0435)\\
Cares which party wins EP elections&     1.104\sym{*}  &  (0.0433)&     1.023         &  (0.0268)\\
Feels European                     &     1.284\sym{**} &  (0.118) &     1.221\sym{***}&  (0.0734)\\
\\
\textit{Controls} \\ \addlinespace
Education                          &     1.064         &  (0.0491)&     0.945         &  (0.0299)\\
Standard of living                 &     0.919         &  (0.0763)&     0.884\sym{*}  &  (0.0492)\\
Neither left nor right             &     1.127         &  (0.0784)&     1.018         &  (0.0493)\\
Evaluation of govt econ performance&     0.934         &  (0.0349)&     1.037         &  (0.0268)\\
Watch election news on TV          &     0.921         &  (0.0469)&     0.946         &  (0.0332)\\
How many days follows news         &     1.095         &  (0.0713)&     1.221\sym{***}&  (0.0528)\\
\midrule
Pseudo R-Squared    &    \mc{0.0227}\\
$\chi^2 $           &    \mc{395.3} \\
P                   & \mc{0.000000} \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\footnotesize Exponentiated coefficients; Standard errors in parentheses.}\\
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the following MWE, I have used `tabularx` in order to make the table as wide as the textwidth by introducing automatic line breaks in the first column. Additionally, I have used `siunitx` in order to align the numbers: (The vertical line on the right indicates the width of the textwidth)

```
\documentclass[legalpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{input-symbols = ()}
\sisetup{table-space-text-post = \sym{***}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\raggedleft{\caption{Explaining imperfect representation through costs and benefits}}
{
    \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\RaggedRight}X*{2}{S[,table-format=1.4,table-align-text-post=false]S[table-format=2.5,table-align-text-post=false]}}
        \hline\hline
        \\
                                 &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{Dep. variable: Quality of representation}             \\
                                 &                                                             \\
                                 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Misrepresented}              &      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Indifferent}            \\
                                 &  \cline{1-4}      &          &                   &          \\
                                 &   {Odds Ratio}      &     {SE}   &      {Odds Ratio}   &   {SE}     \\
\hline
\\
\textit{Benefits}                                                                              \\
\\
Positive evaluation                &     1.245\sym{***}&  (0.0750)&     1.156\sym{***}&  (0.0459)\\
EU economic policy influence       &     1.015         &  (0.0302)&     1.001         &  (0.0205)\\
\\
\textit{Costs}                                                                              \\
\\
Immigration should decrease        &     0.830\sym{***}&  (0.0364)&     1.007         &  (0.0307)\\
EP doesn't consider citiz. concerns&     0.874\sym{**} &  (0.0451)&     1.022         &  (0.0357)\\
\\
\textit{Context}                                                                              \\
\\
New EU12                           &     0.937         &  (0.0947)&     1.715\sym{***}&   (0.116)\\
EU spending(log)                   &     0.993         &  (0.0510)&     0.953         &  (0.0342)\\
N dimensions party competition     &     0.874\sym{*}  &  (0.0514)&     1.031         &  (0.0401)\\
\\
\textit{Salience}                                                                              \\
\\
My voice counts                    &     0.541\sym{***}&  (0.0675)&     0.967         &  (0.0677)\\
EU deals with imp issues           &     1.003         &  (0.0684)&     0.921         &  (0.0435)\\
Cares which party wins EP elections&     1.104\sym{*}  &  (0.0433)&     1.023         &  (0.0268)\\
Feels European                     &     1.284\sym{**} &  (0.118) &     1.221\sym{***}&  (0.0734)\\
\\
\textit{Controls}                                                                              \\
\\
Education                          &     1.064         &  (0.0491)&     0.945         &  (0.0299)\\
Standard of living                 &     0.919         &  (0.0763)&     0.884\sym{*}  &  (0.0492)\\
Neither left nor right             &     1.127         &  (0.0784)&     1.018         &  (0.0493)\\
Evaluation of govt econ performance&     0.934         &  (0.0349)&     1.037         &  (0.0268)\\
Watch election news on TV          &     0.921         &  (0.0469)&     0.946         &  (0.0332)\\
How many days follows news         &     1.095         &  (0.0713)&     1.221\sym{***}&  (0.0528)\\
\hline
Pseudo R-Square                  &    {0.0227}         &          &                   &          \\
$\chi^2 $                            &     {395.3}         &          &                   &          \\
P                                &  {0.000000}         &          &                   &          \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize Exponentiated coefficients; Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
        \end{tabularx}
}
    \end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Personally, I would also use the horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package and replace some of the blank lines by the `\addlinespace` command:

```
    \documentclass[legalpaper]{article}

    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{input-symbols = ()}
    \sisetup{table-space-text-post = \sym{***}}

    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{table}
    \raggedleft{\caption{Explaining imperfect representation through costs and benefits}}
    {
        \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
            \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\RaggedRight}X*{2}{S[,table-format=1.4,table-align-text-post=false]S[table-format=2.5,table-align-text-post=false]}}
            \toprule
                                     &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{Dep. variable: Quality of representation}             \\

                                     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Misrepresented}              &      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Indifferent}            \\
                                     \cmidrule{2-5}
                                     &   {Odds Ratio}      &     {SE}   &      {Odds Ratio}   &   {SE}     \\
    \midrule
    \textit{Benefits}\\ \addlinespace
    Positive evaluation                &     1.245\sym{***}&  (0.0750)&     1.156\sym{***}&  (0.0459)\\
    EU economic policy influence       &     1.015         &  (0.0302)&     1.001         &  (0.0205)\\
    \\
    \textit{Costs}\\ \addlinespace
    Immigration should decrease        &     0.830\sym{***}&  (0.0364)&     1.007         &  (0.0307)\\
    EP doesn't consider citiz. concerns&     0.874\sym{**} &  (0.0451)&     1.022         &  (0.0357)\\
    \\
    \textit{Context} \\ \addlinespace
    New EU12                           &     0.937         &  (0.0947)&     1.715\sym{***}&   (0.116)\\
    EU spending(log)                   &     0.993         &  (0.0510)&     0.953         &  (0.0342)\\
    N dimensions party competition     &     0.874\sym{*}  &  (0.0514)&     1.031         &  (0.0401)\\
    \\
    \textit{Salience} \\ \addlinespace
    My voice counts                    &     0.541\sym{***}&  (0.0675)&     0.967         &  (0.0677)\\
    EU deals with imp issues           &     1.003         &  (0.0684)&     0.921         &  (0.0435)\\
    Cares which party wins EP elections&     1.104\sym{*}  &  (0.0433)&     1.023         &  (0.0268)\\
    Feels European                     &     1.284\sym{**} &  (0.118) &     1.221\sym{***}&  (0.0734)\\
    \\
    \textit{Controls}\\ \addlinespace
    Education                          &     1.064         &  (0.0491)&     0.945         &  (0.0299)\\
    Standard of living                 &     0.919         &  (0.0763)&     0.884\sym{*}  &  (0.0492)\\
    Neither left nor right             &     1.127         &  (0.0784)&     1.018         &  (0.0493)\\
    Evaluation of govt econ performance&     0.934         &  (0.0349)&     1.037         &  (0.0268)\\
    Watch election news on TV          &     0.921         &  (0.0469)&     0.946         &  (0.0332)\\
    How many days follows news         &     1.095         &  (0.0713)&     1.221\sym{***}&  (0.0528)\\
    \midrule
    Pseudo R-Square                  &    {0.0227}         &          &                   &          \\
    $\chi^2 $                            &     {395.3}         &          &                   &          \\
    P                                &  {0.000000}         &          &                   &          \\
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize Exponentiated coefficients; Standard errors in parentheses}\\
    \multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
            \end{tabularx}
    }
        \end{table}


    \end{document}
```

[image]

---

Lastly, please nothe that I have removed the incorrect `12` option form the documentclass. Probably, you wanted to use `12pt` instead. If you use the latter option, your table will most likely not fit onto one page any more, so you might either allow for pagebreaks or use a smaller font size for the contents of the table.

---

In the following example, I have temporarily decreased the margins on both sides of the text in order to horizontally center the otherwise too wide table. (The short text below the table is generated with `\lipsum` from the `lipsum` package in order to show the textwidth.) You can also decrease the font size in the table and use a smaller width as the argument of `adjustwidth`.

```
\documentclass[legalpaper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{input-symbols = ()}
\sisetup{table-space-text-post = \sym{***}}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
    \begin{table}
\raggedleft{\caption{Explaining imperfect representation through costs and benefits}}

    \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-0.12\textwidth}{-0.12\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{l*{2}{S[,table-format=1.4,table-align-text-post=false]S[table-format=2.5,table-align-text-post=false]}}
        \toprule
                                 &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{Dep. variable: Quality of representation}             \\

                                 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Misrepresented}              &      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Indifferent}            \\
                                 \cmidrule{2-5}
                                 &   {Odds Ratio}      &     {SE}   &      {Odds Ratio}   &   {SE}     \\
\midrule
\textit{Benefits}\\ \addlinespace
Positive evaluation                &     1.245\sym{***}&  (0.0750)&     1.156\sym{***}&  (0.0459)\\
EU economic policy influence       &     1.015         &  (0.0302)&     1.001         &  (0.0205)\\
\\
\textit{Costs}\\ \addlinespace
Immigration should decrease        &     0.830\sym{***}&  (0.0364)&     1.007         &  (0.0307)\\
EP doesn't consider citiz. concerns&     0.874\sym{**} &  (0.0451)&     1.022         &  (0.0357)\\
\\
\textit{Context} \\ \addlinespace
New EU12                           &     0.937         &  (0.0947)&     1.715\sym{***}&   (0.116)\\
EU spending(log)                   &     0.993         &  (0.0510)&     0.953         &  (0.0342)\\
N dimensions party competition     &     0.874\sym{*}  &  (0.0514)&     1.031         &  (0.0401)\\
\\
\textit{Salience} \\ \addlinespace
My voice counts                    &     0.541\sym{***}&  (0.0675)&     0.967         &  (0.0677)\\
EU deals with imp issues           &     1.003         &  (0.0684)&     0.921         &  (0.0435)\\
Cares which party wins EP elections&     1.104\sym{*}  &  (0.0433)&     1.023         &  (0.0268)\\
Feels European                     &     1.284\sym{**} &  (0.118) &     1.221\sym{***}&  (0.0734)\\
\\
\textit{Controls}\\ \addlinespace
Education                          &     1.064         &  (0.0491)&     0.945         &  (0.0299)\\
Standard of living                 &     0.919         &  (0.0763)&     0.884\sym{*}  &  (0.0492)\\
Neither left nor right             &     1.127         &  (0.0784)&     1.018         &  (0.0493)\\
Evaluation of govt econ performance&     0.934         &  (0.0349)&     1.037         &  (0.0268)\\
Watch election news on TV          &     0.921         &  (0.0469)&     0.946         &  (0.0332)\\
How many days follows news         &     1.095         &  (0.0713)&     1.221\sym{***}&  (0.0528)\\
\midrule
Pseudo R-Square                  &    {0.0227}         &          &                   &          \\
$\chi^2 $                            &     {395.3}         &          &                   &          \\
P                                &  {0.000000}         &          &                   &          \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize Exponentiated coefficients; Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
        \end{tabular}

\end{adjustwidth}
    \end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer, my problem is that I need the variables displayed on a the same line... I can't start new lines, I will show this on a presentation, it will be unreadable otherwise...

Comment: @MatteoBulgarelli: I have edited my anser according to your request.

Comment: @MatteoBulgarelli: Could you please explain what you mean by "show this in a presentation"? Do you use latex to create the slides for the presentation? If so, why do you use the `article` documentclass?